# COM Interop - Member not found

Tags: c++, com

I'm try to write a plugin for a 3rd party product.  This takes the form of a native C++ DLL, which implements a specified interface from a supplied type library.  My plugin is getting loaded successfully, and the methods described by the interface are being called at the expected points, I can write out a log file from my plugin and query a web service, so far so good.

However, for my plugin to query the main program, the `Initialize()` method passes an `IDispatch` interface.  I'm attempting use this interface with some code like this:

```
Initialize(LPDISPATCH pDispArchivingControl) {
  LPOLESTR ptName = L"currentVaultId";
  HRESULT hr= pDispArchivingControl->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &ptName, 1, 
                         LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, &dispID);
  // add parameters, etc
  hr = pDispArchivingControl->Invoke(dispID, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, 
                   DISPATCH_METHOD, &dp, pvResult, NULL, NULL);
  // hr = 0x80020003 Member not found.
}
```

The first section, `GetIDsOfNames()`, does what I think it should, i.e. putting the names of methods from the program's documentation into `ptName` gives me different values in `dispID` - 15, 27, and so on.

The second section, `Invoke()`, always returns HRESULT 0x80020003 (Member not found).

I found some solutions listed here: [HOWTO: Troubleshoot "Member Not Found" 0x80020003 Error](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172108). For resolution 1, I tried both DISPATCH_METHOD and DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET as the fourth parameter.  Am I right in assuming 2 and 3 cannot apply to me as I am getting the values back in dispID?  I'm not sure how to change these either.

I've kinda out of ideas now, and Google is not helping me any further - can anyone suggest what to do next?

---

UPDATE: This is what one of the methods looks like in oleview. I couldn't find it in the treeview but was able to open it with File > View TypeLib...

[image: method seen in oleview]

Comment: Doesn't sound much like a method.  We can't see dp, it is actually an indexed property?  Why are you using late binding when you have a type library?  Look at it with Oleview.exe

Comment: @HansPassant I'm using late binding because I don't know what I'm doing :) I'm quite new to C++ and COM. I did also try using an #import with the type library but couldn't work out how to connect the passed interface to it - I tried creating an instance and assigning the interface to it, which compiles but gives "invalid pointer" at runtime.  Is #import better for this situation? or something else?

Comment: The import should create an `IArchivingControl` interface and maybe even an `IArchivingControlPtr` ATL smart pointer class if you're lucky. If you've got the smart pointer then just try assigning your IDispatch to it and see if you get a non-null object you can then call against. If you don't have a smart pointer, try calling `QueryInterface` on the IDispatch with the IID_IArchivingControl and it should create an IArchivingControl interface for you. Don't forget to `Release` them both when you're done.

Comment: How did we get from "TortoisCount" to "currentVaultId"?  They are two very different source control programs.  Tortoise is a wrapper for the freeware SVN.  I've heard of Vault, that's a commercial SCCS.  Are you trying to use late binding to try to ignore fundamental differences between programs?  That's a fail whale.

Comment: @HansPassant sorry to be confusing - the code sample was just a couple of example lines to show what I was doing.  The screenshot is the real type library.  I was using the real function names with `GetIDsOfNames()`, I was using the documentation supplied with the product for those

Comment: Hmm, massive moving target here.  Use the type library.  They were explicitly designed to avoid having to write the kind of code you posted in your question.

Comment: I did try swapping the fourth argument to DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET but still got member not found - was I doing that wrong?

Comment: @Colin Oops, yes, I missed you'd already mentioned that. I think if you're trying to use currentVaultId then you do need DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET - there must be something else wrong. But I agree with Hans - go with the typed interface if you can.

Comment: Thank you both for your recommendation, I am going to try the typed interface now.  if you put your comment as an answer I will accept/upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer to this question, given by Hans Passant and Rup in the comments, is not to use late binding, but to `#import` the type library.

I put this in `stdafx.h`:

```
#import "ArchivingControl.tlb" raw_interfaces_only, raw_native_types, named_guids, auto_search
```

And this in my .cpp file:

```
ArchivingControl::IArchivingControlPtr JTArchivingControlPtr;
STDMETHODIMP CMyClass::Initialize(LPDISPATCH pDispArchivingControl)
{
   JTArchivingControlPtr = pDispArchivingControl;
   return S_OK;
}
STDMETHODIMP CMyClass::OtherFunction()
{
   BSTR pVaultId;
   JTArchivingControlPtr->get_currentVaultId(&pVaultId);
   return S_OK;
}
```

And now everything works nicely, plus I have way less code now - Thanks!